# Ensure that Room No. of a Course's Section is within the permitted Rooms for that Course with some Constraint

Tags: database, database-design, mysql, relational-database

I am facing difficulties establishing constraints in the following situation. This is a hypothetical scenario for practicing DB designing.

> Imagine, a rule in a School states that the `Courses` there will be taken in some fixed `Rooms`. E.g: *Math Course* can only be taken in Room 101, 102 and 110. Now, a `Course` can have many `Sections`. So, I need to make sure that any `Section` of the *Math Course* is taken only in the specified `Rooms`.

**NOTE:** A particular Section will be taken in only one room. That is, *Section 1* of the *Math course* will be taken in *Room 101* only

Now, I make a `Course-Room` relation by taking the PK of both `Course` and `Room`. The `Section` relation is created by taking the PK of `Course` and adding the `Section` Number with it.

For storing the `Rooms` of the `Sections`, a relation `Section-Room` is created. The `Section-Room` table should only contain rows that conform to the `Course-Room` relation. **How can I create a constraint from this relation to the `Course-Room` relation?**

---

A sample ERD is created here: https://dbdiagram.io/d/5e4433459e76504e0ef15e24

The Schema as [DBML](https://www.dbml.org/docs/#table-definition) is pasted below as a backup.

```
// Store info about a Course
Table course {
  course_pk int [pk] 
  course_code varchar(13) [not null, unique]
  course_name varchar(200) [not null]
}

Table room {
  room_pk int [pk]
  room_no int
}

Table section {
  section_pk int [pk]
  course_id int
  section int
}
Ref: section.course_id > course.course_pk

Table course_room {
  course_room_pk int [pk]
  course_id int
  room_id int
}
Ref: course_room.course_id > course.course_pk
Ref: course_room.room_id > room.room_pk
```

Comment: I didn't get why you assert sections must be directly related to rooms? Courses are related to Rooms, Sections are related to Courses. That a Section is related to a Room is now implied indirectly; it doesn't need to be expressed?

Comment: Then how to know in which room class of a particular Section will be held?

Comment: Where is that restriction stated in the question?

Comment: I'll update it. Thanks. I assumed as Section and Course are real world entities, this restriction is implied

Comment: The restriction *is* implied. Many Section has 1 Course. 1 Course has Many Rooms. Thus, for any given section we can find out what rooms it may occur in. It was never stated that a section occurs in a particular room

Comment: Yeah. I see it now. I've updated the question and added it

Answer (score 1):

- 1 course has many rooms
- 1 room has many courses
- 1 course has many sections
- 1 section has 1 course (? Or can the same section appear in multiple courses?)

If a section always occurs in a particular room for a particular course, then it depends on the course-room entity that decomposes the many:many relationship between courses and rooms. This thus establishes the rule that

- 1 section has 1 course-room, that is in the list of rooms that the course takes place in

Comment: To answer your question, let's assume that one section won't appear in multiple courses. Though section here is simply an integer

Comment: I can infer the 1 section has 1 course-room part. But I can't figure out how to restrict the possible room values of that section based on its coure-room. I'd need to store the course's pk in section-room table to establish a foreign key on course-room

Comment: @JahirulIslam, the trick is that the Section table does not contain a `room_id` foreign key relation into the Room table, but a `course_room_id` foreign key relation into the Cource_room table, with the additional constraint that the course_id's must match (possibly not expressed in the dababase itself).

Comment: So, the `Section-Room` relation would be something like `(section_id, course_room_id)` ?

Comment: Yes: a section doesn't link to a room, it links to a course-room (which links to a room). If you want to know what single room a section is in you get to it via course-room